# Databricks: Best practice for creating queries for data transformation?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

My apologies in advance for sounding like a newbie. This is really just a curiosity question I have as an outsider observing my team clash with our client. Please ask any questions you have, and I will try my best to answer it.

Currently, we are storing our transformation queries in a DynamoDB table. When needed, we pull into Databricks and execute the query. Simple as that. Our client has called this out as “hard coding” (more on that soon)

Our client has come up with an alternative that involves creating JSON config files containing the transformation rules (all tables/attributes required, target table names, Alias names, join keys, etc. etc.). From here, the SQL query is dynamically created. This approach is still “hard coding” since these config files would need to be manually edited anytime there is a change in the rules.

The way I see this: I think storing the transform rules in JSON is more business user friendly, but that’s about where I see the pros end. It brings in much more complexity to the code and likely will need to be continuously developed to support new queries. Also, I don’t see anyway to prevent “hard coding”. The client business leads seem to think there is some magical tool to convert plain English text to complex SQL queries

I just wanted to get some experts thoughts on this. Which solution is better, or is there another approach that should be taken?

Comment: Your question is interesting, but it is not in the right place. StackOverflow is a page for unambiguously answered questions, not a discussion forum. Opinion-based questions are not clear cut and there will be something bad for some and good for others.
Discussions focused on diverse opinions can be great, but they just don't fit our format well.

Comment: @LordF Where would be the best place to ask this. Perhaps a Databricks or Spark forum?

Comment: Check this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201994/is-there-a-place-to-ask-opinion-based-questions

Comment: As already pointed out, stackoverflow might not be the place for this question.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ would probably be a better fit since this more concerns the design/architecture or your solution